# How can I insert an else statement to this foreach loop?

Tags: php

I am trying to add an else state to this quiz system to disable the quiz after taking it once.

Been doing several codes but I can't seem to figure out how to implement it.

```php
<?php 
    foreach ($results as $result):
        if((strtotime($result['sdatetime']) <= strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:sa")))  
            && (strtotime($result['edatetime']) > strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"))))
        { 
?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $result['test_name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result['subject']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result['edatetime']; ?></td>
                <td><a href="solveTest.php?var=<?php echo $result['test_id'];?>" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Start Test</a></td>
            </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: *... disable the quiz after taking it once*, how do you remember if someone took the quiz? Via cookie? (Can be removed by clearing cache.) Via Session? (Data is lost once the client closes the browser.) Via IP? (Can be easily changed.) Via some sort of login? Do you have a flag in a database for which quiz they took, if so please provide those details.

Comment: it would be via session. Each user needs to log in before taking their quiz.

Comment: As already said: once they close the browser and reopen it they can take the quiz again. Session is not gonna cut it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? And how is this related to Javascript or jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

> It is quite basics because in this code you can write else statement just after end of if statement.
> it allows you to shows result if condition is true then execute code write under if statement otherwise execute code write in else statement.

```
 <?php foreach ($results as $result):
if((strtotime($result['sdatetime']) <= strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:sa")))  && (strtotime($result['edatetime']) > strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:sa")))  ){ ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $result['test_name'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $result['subject']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result['edatetime']; ?></td>
<td><a href="solveTest.php?var=<?php echo 
$result['test_id'];?>" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Start Test</a></td>
</tr>
<?php } else { ?>

     <!-- wtite your code here -->

<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```